# Type: ParseError Message: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) -- Codeiginiter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a problem. how we use `update_batch()` in controller with multiple data. i want to update my data in field `eta` (input type date with `name="tgl[]"` and `lokasi_order` (input select-option with `name="chk[]"`)

here is my Controller/function :

```
public function proses_order_action($lenght){
    $input = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
    $get_cek = $this->input->post('chk', TRUE);// get all code 1 or 3 from each data to array
    $get_tgl = $this->input->post('tgl', TRUE);
    $i=0;

    $data = while ($i < $lenght) {
        array('lokasi_order' => $get_cek[$i], 'eta' => $get_tgl[$i]);
        /*echo $get_cek[$i];
        echo " ";
        echo $get_tgl[$i];
        echo "<br/>";*/
        $i++;
    };

    /*echo $get_cek[0];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $get_tgl[0];
    $data = array(
        while ( $i <= $lenght) {
            //array('lokasi_order' => $get_cek[$i], 'eta' => $get_tgl[$i]);
            $i++;
        }
    );*/
    $this->db->update_batch('detail_estimasi', $data);

}
```

Here is My View :

```
<section class="content">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Exportable Table -->
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="header">
                    <h2>
                        Proses Order
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <style type="text/css">
                    /*hilangkan exportable dan menyisakan input search di tabel*/
                    .dt-buttons {
                        display: none;
                    }
                </style>
                <div class="body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <?php $y=1; ?>
                        <form method="POST" action="">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                            <tbody>

                                    <tr>
                                        <th>No.</th>
                                        <th style="text-align: center;">Nama Barang</th>
                                        <th style="text-align: center;">Nama Customer</th>
                                        <th style="text-align: center;">No. Polisi</th>
                                        <th style="text-align: center;">Kode Lokasi</th>
                                        <th style="text-align: center;">Estimation Time Arrived</th>
                                    </tr>

                                    <?php
                                        $i = 1;
                                        $count = 0;
                                        foreach($data as $x){
                                    ?>

                                     <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $i++ ?></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $x->nama_item ?></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $x->nama_lengkap ?></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $x->no_polisi ?></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;">
                                            <select class="form-control show-tick" name="chk[]">
                                                <option value="1">Kode 1</option>
                                                <option value="3">Kode 3</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center;">
                                            <input type="date" name="tgl[]">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php $count++;} ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <input type="submit" formaction="<?= base_url('partsman/proses_order_action/'.$count) ?>" name="" class="btn btn-warning waves-effect" value="Order">
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #END# Exportable Table -->

    <!-- Exportable Table -->
</div>
```

Here is my view capture :
[image: Image Capture]

I want to update my data.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function proses_order_action()
{
    $input = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
    $get_cek = $this->input->post('chk', TRUE);
    $get_tgl = $this->input->post('tgl', TRUE);
    foreach($get_cek as $cek)
    {
      $data['lokasi_order']= $cek;
    }
    foreach($get_tgl as $tgl)
    {
      $data['eta'] =$t;
    }

     $this->db->update_batch('detail_estimasi', $data);
}
```

Comment: thankyou, i'try :)

Comment: i got some error with this

Comment: can u tell me what error occurs

Comment: You must specify an index to match on for batch updates.

it is the error message. did i add one parameter into my update_batch ?

Comment: im done with my problem :) Thank you. your solution is open minded for me hehehe :D